# Microsoft Graph's Calendar API doesn't return recurring calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the CalendarView API of Microsoft Graph. Based on the offical documentation: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_calendarview

I did this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2016-9-07&endDateTime=2016-10-02
```

However I don't see any recurring events. I can see other events happens before and after the recurring ones.

More information after the initial posting:
The problem occurs if the date range goes over the week border. For example, I have an recurring event on 2016-09-08, If I set the start date to 2016-09-07 and end date to 2016-09-10, it would work, but if I set the end date to 2016-09-11, the events won't show up.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT Hello Michae, thanks for looking into it. What I found out is that, if the date range goes over the week border, the recurring events would disappear. For example, I have an recurring event on 2016-09-08, If I set the start date to 2016-09-07 and end date to 2016-09-10, it would work, but if I set the end date to 2016-09-11, the events won't show up. PS. I am using the beta API.

Comment: How many results are returned? How many results do you expect? The default page size is 10.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT. Thanks for bringing this up. I just noticed the "@odata.nextLink" property when the result is paged. Following the link getting all results fixed the problem. I guess I was expecting the paged results were in sorted fashion, but I shouldn't have made that assumption without having "OrderBy" in the request. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael Mainer helped to identify the root cause:

The calendar API has a default page size of 10. One should follow the "@odata.nextLink" property to obtain all results. The paged results is not sorted by start date unless "OrderBy" is specifically added.

Answer (score 1):

As [Miaosen Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4416379/miaosen-wang) mention the **default page size is 10**.
As a workaround you can **increase the page size** adding the parameters "**orderby**" and "**top**" to you query.

**params:**

```
$orderby=start/dateTime DESC
$top=100
```

**e.g.**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2016-9-07&endDateTime=2016-10-02&%24$orderby=start/dateTime%20DESC"&%24top=100
```